# How to use @ (at) symbol in package.json in the scripts section (my case: run cucumber-js for tagged features)

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, cucumberjs

we specify different scripts in the scripts section of a package.json file.
I would like to run cucumber-js via the scripts and specify tags to execute only a certain set of tests.

This command runs fine in the command line: npx cucumber-js --tags "@taggedTest"
However, in the scripts section, I get an error.
The scripts section looks like this:

```
...
 "scripts": {
    "e2e": "npx cucumber-js",
    "e2e_taggedTests": "npx cucumber-js --tags \"@taggedTests\"",
    "unitTests": "jest"
  }
...
```

So I escaped the quotation marks, but I cannot escape the @ (at) symbol.
That is why I get this error:

```
Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 1097 while parsing near '...cumber-js --tags \"\@taggedTests\"
```

Is there any way how I can escape the @ (at) symbol in the scripts section to actually use it? It works fine without escaping in other sections like the dependencies section, but I have no idea what to do in the scripts section and have not found anything in the official docs?

Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with \?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know why you are trying to use quotes to mention tags. You can simply use it without quotes. I tried with the repo [here](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-api/blob/master/packages/cucumber-selenium-example/package.json#L12) and it worked using by just appending --tags @test

Comment: I was adding the quotes because you can combine tags that way. However, that is not required right now, so I do it as you suggested and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote the tag expression unless it contains spaces (e.g. a more advanced one like `@foo or @bar`).

See also: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions